# Is it rude to say: "Let us make sure this does not happen again."

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

I was told that "Let us make sure this does not happen again." is disrespectful. My manager had this line at the end of her email to my team. A few found it disrespectful.

Is that so?

Comment: It depends who you're talking to, and what you're talking about. Please add context to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The context and interpretation matters a lot here.  Does this mean the boss just wants everyone to be on guard against this issue?  Or does this mean the boss blames you for the problem, and is threatening you with consequences if it happens again?  It's completely ambiguous.  The ambiguity itself could be purposeful, as a way for the boss to imply you are to blame without actually blaming you.

With so little detail, there's no way for internet strangers to know if your boss was being sincere about everyone working together to fix a problem, or if they were issuing threats and assigning blame.  But if your coworkers believe they are being blamed and threatened then they would certainly find the words rude.